# jquery $.ajax - error handler launches with no apparent error

Tags: jquery, ajax

On http://83.150.87.220/HelsinkiViSe/helsinki-map-application/ajax_test.php you can send a very simple async HTTP request when pushing the button on top of the page.
Bellow is the code for it:

```
var xmlString = "<request><session></session><target_id>20</target_id></request>";

// Build the URL to connect to
var url = "http://83.150.87.220/HelsinkiViSe.dll/load";

$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: url,
    dataType: 'application/xml',
    data: xmlString, 
    success: function(msg) { 
        //var data = JSON.parse(msg); 
        $("#text").html(msg); 
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#text").html(jqXHR+'<br>'+textStatus+'<br>'+errorThrown); 
    }
});
```

As you can see, the request data block is a simple piece of XML:

```
var xmlString = "<request><session></session><target_id>20</target_id></request>";
```

The back-end script is supposed to respond with an XML block as well, which it does (monitoring communication using Firebug and Chrome's "code inspector"). This block is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <target>
    <target_id>20</target_id>
    <plot>20803/3</plot>
    <builder>(makasiini L3)</builder>
    <housing_form>avoin</housing_form>
    <block_name>JätkäHieta</block_name>
    <finnish_year></finnish_year>
    <target_name></target_name>
    <target_address></target_address>
    <office_space></office_space>
    <purpose></purpose>
    <reservations></reservations>
    <contacts></contacts>
  </target>
  <status>OK</status>
  <errormsg></errormsg>
</response>
```

The problem is that the error handler launches nevertheless, and the success handler doesn't. And this is giving me white hairs. Do you know what might the cause for this be and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Andrei

Comment: What happens if you change `url` to be just `/HelsinkiViSe.dll/load`? (Since that's all you need.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Same problem. However, I don't understand what you mean by "Since that's all you need".

Comment: @ Andrei: Since the page is at `http://83.150.87.220/HelsinkiViSe/helsinki-map-application/ajax_test.php` and you're trying to load `http://83.150.87.220/HelsinkiViSe.dll/load`, you can (and in most cases should) use the equivalent relative URL rather than an absolute one. As both URLs start with `http://83.150.87.220`, all you need is `/HelsinkiViSe.dll/load`, which will be resolved relative to the current document.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder That's true, but it didn't change anything. Any ideas on what else might be triggering the error handler and/or why?

Comment: @ Andrei: Yeah, and really it shouldn't have except in a buggy implementation of the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which I'm pretty sure Chrome doesn't have. :-) I *didn't* have any idea what the problem was, but I do now -- I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two and possibly three problems, one of which I'm sure is just debug code:

1. You've told jQuery to use `dataType: "application/xml"`. The `dataType` argument isn't a MIME type, it's a jQuery-specific thing. You want `dataType: "xml"`.
2. (This is probably the debug thing.) In your `success` function, you're passing the XML document into the `html` function, which will raise an error. If you change it to `text` instead, it'll show `"[object Document]"` instead, which makes sense — jQuery has deserialized the XML into an XML `Document` object for you.
3. You're sending the XML string without encoding it. When you specify a string for the `data` argument, **you** are responsible for ensuring it's properly encoded for transit ([reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#sending-data-to-server)). I'm fairly sure you need to change the line

   ```
   data: xmlString
   ```

   ...to

   ```
   data: encodeURIComponent(xmlString)
   ```

   I say "fairly sure" because I don't remember the last time I tried to post XML to a server. But anything you're sending via `POST` should typically be URL-encoded.

[Live working example](http://jsbin.com/uqurin) | [source](http://jsbin.com/uqurin/edit)

Comment: @Andrei: You're welcome! I forgot to mention that for me (using Chrome and JSBin), I *did* get a nice error message from jQuery when using your original code: "Error: No conversion from text to application/xml", which is what pointed me in the right direction. Try it here: http://jsbin.com/uhazex Maybe a difference in jQuery versions? I'm using Chrome, but you mentioned Chrome so I figured you were too...

Comment: You were editing the answer as I was writing my comment to it and didn't notice it :).  The suggestion to change the dataType parameter did the trick indeed. Passing the request response to the 'html' jQuery method also thew an error, but using .text() instead of it simply doesn't display anything (try it please). As for the the 3rd suggestion, it's actually good as it is,  encoding the data actually made the script throw another error. I guess the next step is to parse the response.

Comment: @Andrei: Re `text`: I did try it; in my browser (Chrome) I get what I said, "[object Document]". But you wouldn't want to really pass an XML document into `text` (or `html`) anyway, you'd want to *use* it. For instance, you can do this: http://jsbin.com/uqurin/3 There I've just shown the content of the `plot` element from the response, but you get the idea...

Comment: Absolutely, the html/text methods were only for testing purposes, to make sure the response data was correctly passed as an argument to the success event handler. Once again, thank you for your help!